how to create a version.py file that is updated each time any file is pushed via git
I am hoping to have git create a version.py file that looks like this (where the version is incremented each commit):
# This file is created by the pre-push script
class Version:
    comment = "git commit comment"
    hash = "some git hash"
    version = "0.8.9"

I have tried this:
#!/usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python
import os
import subprocess
import re
import sys

commit_msg_file = sys.argv[1]

with open(commit_msg_file, 'r') as file:
    commit_msg = file.read().strip()

version_file = os.path.abspath('version.py')
hashed_code = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD']).strip().decode('utf-8')

if os.path.exists(version_file):
    print(f'Reading previous {version_file}')

    with open(version_file, 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
        major, minor, patch = map(int, re.search(r'version = "(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)"', content).groups())

    patch += 1
else:
    print(f'Creating new {version_file}')
    major, minor, patch = 0, 0, 1

print(f'Writing contents of {version_file} with "{commit_msg}"')

with open(version_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(f'''# This file is created by the pre-push script
class Version:
    comment = "{commit_msg}"
    hash = "{hashed_code}"
    version = "{major}.{minor}.{patch}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Version.version)
''')
    f.close()

print(f'adding {version_file}')
subprocess.call(['git', 'add', version_file])
# subprocess.call(['git', 'commit', '-m',  comment])
print(f'adding {version_file}')
subprocess.call(['git', 'add', version_file])
# subprocess.call(['git', 'commit', '-m', comment])

I haved tried this in pre-push and repare-commit-msg to no avail...  Is there a better way or a way to fix what I have?
thanks in advance

Don't.  This question is similar to "how to I shoot myself in the foot with a nail gun?"  Anyone who answers such a question with technical guidance is doing you a disservice.  Do NOT store version information in a file in the repo.  Instead, derive the version info from the repo.

But, since the given answers are suggesting pre-commit hooks, which is a terrible technical solution.  If you insist on doing this (you really shouldn't), you want to look into clean/smudge filters.

@WilliamPursell can you recommend a better way to retrieve a version of a release?  There must be a way as I see it everywhere, but I have not seen how to do it.

@WilliamPursell The code is intended to be run by a user that does not have access to the git repo so I am at a loss how to do this somewhat automatically

On further testing, I see that @WilliamPursell is probably right: the commit_msg is still (usually) behind by one commit :-(  I have to believe that this is possible

@WilliamPursell Regarding storing version information in files - isn't that precisely what pyproject.toml files do?

@alex, yes, storing version info in a file is unfortunately extremely common.  That doesn't make it a good idea.

If the user accessing your source code does not have access to the git repo, what do they have access to?  Presumably, you are generating an artifact of some sort (eg, a tarball or a zip file) that they do have access to.  The process that builds that artifact from git should generate the version.py file  from information derived from the git repo.

@WilliamPursell that is an excellent suggestion!  It saves fighting with git and reduces the number of patches.

I tried your script and it works for me if I get the commit message from git directly instead of from a file. The way you coded it, you're expecting the hook caller to pass you an argument with a filename, but I've tested with the pre-commit hook and it doesn't pass any arguments.
I changed it to:
commit_msg = subprocess.check_output(['git','log','-1','--pretty=%B']).strip().decode('utf-8')

and it worked fine for me.

Thanks to @WilliamPursell I have completely removed all of my git-hooks and moved the version.py creation to the script that I use to package the project.  In my main.py, I check for the file.  If its not there, I call the function in my package script to create it with the current release notes, etc.  Once its created, it remains intact until I package the project.  At that time the package script updates the version.py with the latest release notes etc.  This has the added benefit of only incrementing the patch when it is packaged (at which time, the major/minor release should be updated anyway!)

You really, really, really, seriously do not want to do this.  Wherever that version.py script is used, you should instead generate the version number as needed from the git repo.
However, if you choose to ignore that advice, you can do what you want with a smudge/clean filter pair.  eg:
$ mkdir example && cd example && GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR= git init > /dev/null
$ cat > version.py << EOF
>     comment = "@comment@"
>     hash = "@hash@"
>     version = "@version@"
> EOF
$ filter_name=version
$ file=version.py
$ git add $file
$ git commit -m "Add $file" > /dev/null 2>&1
$ printf "%s filter=${filter_name}\n" "${file?}" >> $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.gitattributes
$ git config filter.${filter_name}.clean "git show HEAD:${file?}"
$ git config filter.${filter_name}.smudge 'sed \
>     -e "s/@comment@/$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%s)/" \
>     -e "s/@hash@/$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%h)/" \
>     -e "s/@version@/$(git describe || echo unknown)/"'
$ mkdir -p .git/hooks
$ echo '#!/bin/sh' > .git/hooks/post-commit
$ echo "rm ${file?}; git checkout HEAD ${file?}" >> .git/hooks/post-commit
$ chmod +x .git/hooks/post-commit
$ rm $file
$ git checkout HEAD version.py
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
Updated 1 path from 3ebb23d
$ cat version.py
    comment = "Add version.py"
    hash = "fa06fb3"
    version = "unknown"

The basic idea is that the smudge filter modifies the content of the so that what ends up in your working directory is different than the content that git is actually tracking.  The clean filter modifies the content in your working directory when you commit to git.  So git thinks the content of the file contains a line like hash = "@hash@", but the file you have in your working directory gets modified by sed and ends up looking like hash = "fa06fb3".
